# how to split a sequence in R into multiple sub parts

Tags: r

seq="GAGTAGGAGGAG",how to split this sequence into the following sub sequence "GAG","TAG","GAG","GAG"i.e how to split the sequence in groups of threes

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday `strsplit("GAGTAGGAGGAG", "(?<=.{3})", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: can you please explain am not getting it properly

Comment: This also works:  `library(gsubfn); strapplyc(xx, "...")[[1]]`   where there are three dots in a row.

Comment: I am getting the output if I give the sequence directly but if I give  sequence =readDNAStringSet("a.fasta")
 and then give strsplit(sequence,"(?<=.{3})", perl=TRUE)) am getting error @Pierre Lafortune

Comment: We do not know what the `readDNAStringSet("a.fasta")` output is. How do you expect us to help with it?

Comment: take any fasta file and then assign it to a variable using readDNAStringSet and then try strsplit

Comment: I do not have fasta files. Add a small example of the output to the question in the form `dput(head(readDNAStringSet("a.fasta")))`

Comment: What do you get when you enter `str(readDNAStringSet("a.fasta"))`? Add it to your question

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function called `fixed_split` that will split a character string into equal parts. The regular expression is a lookbehind that matches on `n` elements together:

```
fixed_split <- function(text, n) {
  strsplit(text, paste0("(?<=.{",n,"})"), perl=TRUE)
}

fixed_split("GAGTAGGAGGAG", 3)
[[1]]
[1] "GAG" "TAG" "GAG" "GAG"
```

**Edit**

In your comment you say `sequence ="ATGATGATG"` does not work:

```
strsplit(sequence,"(?<=.{3})", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "ATG" "ATG" "ATG"
```